# Defining "Global Variables" in VB.NET / VS2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm using "GetPrivateProfileString" to successfully read a .ini file.  I'm finding myself having to re-suse various variables in multiple procedures such as Form Loading and other various on click events.

I'd like to simply my code so that I don't have to declare the same variables multiple times.  I tried moving my code to a Class to get more global access without having to redefine the variables multiple times.  A snippet of my code is below and any insight to how I can accomplish this, would be appreciated.

```
Dim MJBLoaderIni as String
MJBLoaderIni = tbBaseMMInstall.Text & "\MJBLoader\MJBLoader.ini"
Dim ConfigDisplayCustomerNumber As String
Dim DisplayCNumber As String
DisplayCNumber = Space(1)

ConfigDisplayCustomerNumber = ApplicationLog.GetPrivateProfileString("MJBLOADER", "DISPLAYCUSTOMERNUMBER", "$", DisplayCNumber, 255, MJBLoaderIni)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use "**Public**" variable type and declare it in **module** level .. like this

You can makeit as **Mymodule.vb**

```
Public MJBLoaderIni as String
```

So your `MJBLoaderIni` will recognize in your all app in same project

Sample in your **Form1**..

```
Class Form1
  MJBLoaderIni = tbBaseMMInstall.Text & "\MJBLoader\MJBLoader.ini"
  Dim ConfigDisplayCustomerNumber As String
  Dim DisplayCNumber As String

  Private Sub Form_Load( .. ) handles Form.Load
    DisplayCNumber = Space(1)
    ConfigDisplayCustomerNumber = ApplicationLog.GetPrivateProfileString("MJBLOADER",   "DISPLAYCUSTOMERNUMBER", "$", DisplayCNumber, 255, MJBLoaderIni)
  End Sub
End Class
```

In your **Form2** ..

```
Class Form2
  Private Sub Button1_Click( .. ) handles Button1.Click

    Msgbox(MJBLoaderIni)  '------> this will show your MJBLoaderIni

  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: When I do that, MJBLoaderIni is recognized within other elements but struggling with how to initialize the filename (2nd line of above code).  Would I put this all into a procedure within the Module?  Do you have a little more sample code that might point me in the direct direction?

Comment: @GeorgeVaisey .. you should remove the first line in your code and you can start with second one .. and you can keep it in your form class .. and it should work ..

Answer (score 0):

I created a Global Variables class where I create the global variables needed through the application and then populate on form load the values I need.